# sub-series matching, graph matching

Tags: graph-theory, dynamic-programming, bipartite-graphs

Let $A=\{a_{1}...,a_{N}\}$ and $B=\{b_{1},...,b_{M}\}$ be finite sets of integers, such that $N \geq M$.

Find a mutually-exclusive covering of size $M$: $A_{1},...,A_{M}⊂A$ that is monotonic, meaning: if $a_{i} \in A_{l}$ and $a_{j} \in A_{m},$ and $l > m$, then necessarily $i\geq j$. 
And finally, I want the matching to minimize:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{M} \Bigg| b_{k} - \bigg(\sum_{a\in A_k} a\bigg)\Bigg|.$$

I'm not sure I've formulated this correctly, so here's the actual setup I'm interested in:

I have a paragraph of text in two languages ($A$ and $B$). Each is composed of sentences of differing lengths (e.g. the 1st sentence in $A$ is of length $a_{1}$, and $A$ has $N$ sentences, $B$ has $M$ sentences). I want to match the sentences: for instance, the 3rd and 4th sentences in $A$ are a translation of the 3rd sentence of $B$.

Here is an example for lengths of $A$ and $B$:

$A = [56, 156, 117, 170, 214, 97, 454, 177, 141, 173, 102, 90, 295, 259, 222, 54, 36, 152, 178, 154, 100, 117, 315, 375, 155, 72]$

$B = [59, 192, 114, 156, 221, 537, 149, 158, 176, 72, 92, 297, 320, 180, 68, 36, 133, 144, 179, 79, 163, 277, 487, 75]$

I hope it makes sense; Also an approximate solution would help.

Perhaps this better fits stackoverflow?
thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: I've edited your question,  please check if I correctly guessed your intentions. Besides, have you tried the dynamic programming approach? For example for a cubic solution you could try defining $t[n][m]$ as the best matching of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ to $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ and generate the next cell simply by going through all the options available for $A_{m+1}$—there are at most $N$ of them.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; Can you please elaborate some more on your approach for the dynamic programming? it sounds like the right direction, but perhaps would you elaborate on the induction assumption and step? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A sketch of the solution:**

Denote by $t[n][m]$ the cost of the best matching of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ to $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ and observe, that we can calculate $t[n][m]$ using only the values of $t[i][j]$ for smaller values of $i$ and $j$.
More precisely, we define $t : \{0,\ldots,N\} \times \{1,\ldots,M\} \to \mathbb{N}$ as

$$
t[n][m] = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle0 & \text{ if } n = 0, \\ 
\displaystyle\Big|b_1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\Big| & \text{ if } m = 1, \\
\displaystyle\min_{i = 0}^{n} \left(t[i][m-1]
   + \Big|b_m - \sum_{k=i+1}^{n}a_k\Big|\right) & \text{ otherwise}. \\
\end{cases}
$$

This algorithm will take $O(N^2M)$ time to calculate $t[N][M]$, which will be the cost of the solution you are looking for. To construct the actual matching just store the indices that realize the minima, and you will be able to reconstruct exactly the whole partition.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have time for more than just a sketch.

Comment: I appreciate it! I'll soon dive into it and update :-)

Comment: thanks a lot. great solution, implemented and works great. I've learned something today :-)

Comment: @zuuz Great it solved your problem. Nevertheless, take into account that this is a basic approach, thus it is quite slow. In fact, with real-world data, I think that you could speed-up things a lot. If the measure you want would behave approximately bitonic (just a hypothesis, it is possible), then not only you can find the minimum faster, but you could perhaps avoid calculating a lot of unnecessary cells. You won't have a _guarantee_ that it is an optimal result, but in real-world applications you may not need that (or just fallback to the slow algorithm if the instance is troublesome).

Comment: I'm doing a paragraph by paragraph matching. Thus, n~20, so this is pretty acceptable time. If I'd go for entire book, then it would be much compute intensive. If you have the time, would you mind pointing me to what you mean by "approximately bitonic", and consequently why I can find the minimum faster? Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @zuuz A bitonic sequence is if it monotonically increases and then monotonically decreases. In such a case you can use a modification of binary search to find the maximum (in your case you find a minimum of a sequence that would go down and then up). By approximately I mean that there might be some local perturbations, e.g. $1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6,8$ is not increasing, but it is close—with some tweaking you can use binary search on such sequences too. If this is true, then it just might be possible to fill out only the best "diagonal" of the $t$ array and its neighboring cells.